# model view presenter c# how to manage form controllers?

Tags: c#

I want to populate the combobox , through the model class, when the form is loaded, the combobox looks like this. there is a main form, if you click on the product button, the value of the combobox looks like this

```
 public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> GetCategory()
    {
        var categoryList = new List<CategoryModel>();
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT id, name FROM category";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var categoryModell = new CategoryModel
                    {
                        Id = (int)reader[0],
                        Name = reader[1].ToString()
                    };
                    categoryList.Add(categoryModell);
                }
            }
        }
        return categoryList;
    }
```

presenter code

```
private void LoadCategoryList()
    {
        categoryList = repository.GetCategory();
        categoryBindingSource.DataSource = categoryList;
    }
```

and forms (view)

```
  private void ProductView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox_Category.DisplayMember = "name";
        comboBox_Category.ValueMember = "id";
        comboBox_Category.Text = "Select";
    }
 public void SetCategoryListBindingSource(BindingSource categoryList)
    {
        comboBox_Category.DataSource = categoryList;
    }
```

main form

```
public partial class MainView : Form, IMainView
{
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btn_Product.Click += delegate { ShowProductView?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); }; 
        Btn_korzina.Click += delegate { ShowKorzinaView?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); };
}
    
    public event EventHandler ShowProductView;
    public event EventHandler ShowKorzinaView;
```

}
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91WV3.png)

combobox should look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQofb.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @PalleDue , combobox not loading data from database correctly

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` should have the right case: `comboBox_Category.DisplayMember = "Name";        comboBox_Category.ValueMember = "Id";`

Comment: @PalleDue, If I'm not mistaken, am I correct? 
If I'm not mistaken, am I correct? if you look at the second image it looks right there

Comment: You are missing this: "comboBox_Category.DataSource = categoryBindingSource"

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues , sorry, sorry fixed it, but it does not help, when loading the form through the main form, everything is displayed correctly, but if you click again, everything looks like the image

Comment: If click where? Can you post that code here?

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues  yes, btn_Product.click , 
in the image is called product.  posted code

Comment: Some part is missing and I cannot figure out what....how are you binding the controls to the object?